# QGraphicsPixmapItem doesn't show in QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qt5, qgraphicsview

I subclassed QGraphicsView (class Display)  and implemented drag and drop from a QTableView. The QGraphicsScene has in it  preexisting items and the scene()->itemsBoundingRect covers the entire earth.
If I artificially set the QGraphicsPixmapItem's boundingRect to the viewPort() of the QGraphicsView, I don't see the QPixmap I set in the QGraphicsPixmapItem and added to the scene(). If I fitInView the scene()->itemsBoundingRect, the pixmap is dropped on the whole world. I would like it dropped on my viewport, but essentially fitInView viewPort doesn't show the item, even though according to debug it's visible and notObscured().

```
void Display::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent* event)
{

    event->acceptProposedAction();
    update();
}

void Display::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent* event){
    event->acceptProposedAction();
    update();
}
```

---

```
  void TableView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
        QDrag* drag = new QDrag(this);
        QMimeData *mime = new QMimeData();
        drag->setMimeData(mime);
        QImage image("/Users/sb/Downloads/puffin.jpeg");
        mime->setImageData(image);
        drag->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image).scaled(10,10));
        drag->exec();
        QTableView::mouseMoveEvent(event);
```

### }

Edited to try @Eyllanesc suggestion

```
void Display::dropEvent(QDropEvent* event)
{

    setCacheMode(QGraphicsView::CacheBackground);
    setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);

    if(event->mimeData()->hasImage())
    {
        pixMap = qvariant_cast<QPixmap>(event->mimeData()->imageData());
        pixMap = pixMap.scaledToHeight(10);
        pixMap = pixMap.scaledToWidth(10);
        bool h = pixMap.isNull(); //returns false

        posn = mapToScene(event->pos());

        QRectF ff  = mapToScene(viewport()->geometry()).boundingRect();
        bool ps = ff.contains(posn); //returns true

        item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixMap);
        scene()->addItem(item);

        item->setPos( posn);
        item->setZValue(100);
        item->setVisible(true);
        item->setOpacity(1.0);
        item->update();
        scene()->update();
        auto lView = qobject_cast<QGraphicsView*>(this);
        lView->fitInView(ff, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);// no pixmap is shown
        invalidateScene(ff);
        bool i = item->isObscured(); //returns false
        repaint();
        update();
    }
    event->acceptProposedAction();

}
```

-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the next part I show you a working example of how to implement drag-and-drop from a QTableView to a QGraphicsView:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDrag>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QMimeData>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <random>
#include <QStandardItemModel>


static std::random_device rd;
static std::mt19937 rng(rd());


class TableView: public QTableView{
public:
    using QTableView::QTableView;
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
        if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
            dragStartPosition = event->pos();
    }
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
        if (!(event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton))
            return;
        if ((event->pos() - dragStartPosition).manhattanLength()
                < QApplication::startDragDistance())
            return;

        QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
        QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;

        // create image
        QImage image(100, 100, QImage::Format_RGB32);
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(0, 255);
        image.fill(QColor(uni(rng), uni(rng), uni(rng)));

        mimeData->setImageData(image);
        drag->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image).scaled(10,10));
        drag->setMimeData(mimeData);

        drag->exec();
        QTableView::mouseMoveEvent(event);
    }
private:
    QPoint dragStartPosition;
};

class Display: public QGraphicsView{
public:
    using QGraphicsView::QGraphicsView;
protected:
    void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event){
        if(event->mimeData()->hasFormat("application/x-qt-image"))
            event->acceptProposedAction();
    }

    void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event){
        if (event->source() == this)
            return;
        QPixmap pixmap = qvariant_cast<QPixmap>(event->mimeData()->imageData());
        QGraphicsPixmapItem *pixmap_item = scene()->addPixmap(pixmap);
        pixmap_item->setPos(mapToScene(event->pos()));
        event->acceptProposedAction();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    QHBoxLayout* lay = new QHBoxLayout(&w);
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    Display view(&scene);
    view.setAcceptDrops(true);
    TableView table;
    QStandardItemModel model(10, 10);
    table.setModel(&model);
    lay->addWidget(&table);
    lay->addWidget(&view);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: this is excellent work, Eyllanesc! Thank you so much! So fresh and clean! I'd like to post my effort too because I had a question in it. I have the extra complication that I set the viewport manually in my drag and drop example, and in the view I've chosen, my pixmap looks huge! If I drop it on the original view it is fine.

Comment: @JoJoAndChickie I did not understand, if you want to change the size of the pixmap then change the size of the pixmap saved in setImageData, in my case it is 100x100, remember that one thing is the setPixmap where the size is 10x10 and another the setImageData that is 100x100 . If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.

Comment: yes, your answer helped tremendously and answered my questions. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have a minimal verifiable complete example related to this I need help with. The issue will be clear when I post the code. Should I start a new thread? It's about drag and drop but fiddling with the viewport and how it affects the pixmap size from viewport to viewport.

Comment: @JoJoAndChickie You have to create another question, but I stress it must be a [mcve], the code that you put in your question is not, my code on the other hand if it is. Do you have a complete code such as mine?

Comment: yes i do! It's my own code! I'll post it tonight. And thank you so much! Your code taught me a lot about the elegant way of doing things!

Comment: @JoJoAndChickie Hopefully not pieces of code, that is, there is no need to patch code.

Comment: I’ll be posting the entire cpp and h files, they are not bloated.

Comment: I just had to set the QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations flag for the pixmap item I had dropped, and it retained its 20x20 size in the zoomed in view. So the problem is resolved and I don't need to start a new thread! Thank you so much for all your guidance.

Comment: OMG! Just adding that flag made my actual project work too! Thank you thank you thank you!!!